# Convert Java Pattern replaceAll to c#

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have this Java code that I need to traslate to C#

```
private static final Pattern MISSING_PRODUCT_AT_START = Pattern.compile("^\\(( |;|null|compatible|windows|android|linux).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

and

```
result = MISSING_SPACE.matcher(result).replaceAll("$1 $2");
```

The first part can be converted with Regex to:

```
 private static readonly Regex MISSING_SPACE = new Regex("(/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)([A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z]+ )", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but about the second part, I dunno exactly what is the meaning of Java `replaceAll`, I am not a Java expert

Just to explain the context, I am translating an open source library from Java to .NET

How can be traslated `.replaceAll("$1 $2");` to C#?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @shmose so it's equivalent to:  result = MISSING_SPACE.Replace(result, "$1 $2"); ?

Sorry I don't need the msdn explanation, I know very well .NET, simply I don't know if the code that I am writing produces the same results of Java

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti As far as I can tell Java's `replaceAll` is the same as `Replace`.  Both will replace all matches, Java is just being more verbose with the method name.  The best way to find out is just to test it.

Comment: @juharr thank you. Yes I know the only way to find out if the code I am translating is equivalent is to test. However this part with regex is a bit delicate and not easy to test, so just wanted know the opinion of an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the docs of [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)), we can see that it does this:

> Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string.

Which is the same as what [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) does in .NET:

> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

So you can translate the line to::

```
result = MISSING_SPACE.Replace(result, "$1 $2");
```

The word `all` in `replaceAll` kind of suggests that it does something different from `Replace`, but I think that's just to distinguish it from `replaceFirst` and `replaceLast`.

Comment: What's `replaceEnd`?

Comment: @shmosel oops! I meant `replaceLast`.

Comment: Never heard of it.